# What is the part of speech (word class) of to-infinitive?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What is the part of speech (word class) of **to-infinitive**?

as example:

> I forgot **to send** the letter.

***I***: the part of speech (word class) is *pronoun* and the word function (clause element) is *subject*.

***forgot***: the part of speech & and the word function is *verb*.

***to send***: ??

***the letter***: the part of speech is *noun* (*the* is *determiner*) and the word function is *object*.

Comment: *to send the letter* is the object of the verb *forgot*, *the letter* is the object of the verb *send*.

Comment: The part of speech is a verb, more specifically, non-finite verb.

Comment: "To send" is not a single constituent, but two separate constituents: 'To' is a "subordinator" functioning as "marker", and 'forgot' is a plain form "verb" functioning as "predicator" (head of the verb phrase _forgot to send the letter_).

Answer (score -4):

In traditional grammar, the infinitive ("to X") is a *noun*, the form of a verb that names the action of the verb.[Daily Grammar](http://www.dailygrammar.com/Lesson-220-Noun-Infinitives.htm).

> I want to play the piano.

The *subject* is "I". The *verb* is "want".  The *direct object* is "to play" the *indirect object* is "the piano".

Among current grammarians, however, infinitives are not thought of as nouns in English. A summary of some current thought may be found here: [Education First](http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/).
For the best understanding of how such forms as infinitives might be viewed by grammarians, one will need to study from time to time what is written about them.
In your example:

> I forgot to send the letter.

"to send" is the *direct object* of "forgot", no matter what part of speech it might be.

Comment: Not my DV, but *the piano* is the obj for *play* not the indirect object. *Play* is a monotransitive verb, it takes only one object.

Comment: @178049... I was sure the verb in the sentence was "want"

Comment: This is counter to actual understanding of such complements and clauses. See [here](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/ch9.html#sc) for a basic syntactician's view. "To send" is a verb ("send") that is given inflection by the infinitive marker "to".